# Trying to read a serial port, device or resource busy

Tags: linux, usb, serial-port

I'm trying to read the data from a GPS module. It uses TTL communication and I have an adapter to convert it to USB which is connected to my computer.

I can get data from it using cgps, but I need to have more base level communication with it.

When I try

`gpscat -s 9600 /dev/ttyUSB0`

I get

`OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB0'`

I've tried `lsof`, `fuser`, `ps -ef | grep`, `ps aux | grep`, and I can't figure out what is using the port and thus I can't stop it.

Comment: My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761222/trouble-getting-consistent-gps-data-from-simcom-7600-modem) is related so I put a bounty on it too

Comment: Does `lsof` say anything about `ttyUSB0`? Does `sudo pkill -9 ttyUSB0` help? If nothing shows anything, that means that no process has opened the device and the problem is elsewhere. In case this is a permissions problen, try `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: Is `cgps` still running when you attempt to connect manually? Do you have any other `screen` sessions that might be hiding the open process?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes just `lsof /dev/ttyUSB0` is insufficient and you need `sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB0` to see which process is using the file/port.

For example, with just `lsof /dev/ttyUSB3` I don't see anything, but `sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB3` reveals that ModemManager is using the port:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is your username already in the dailout group, if not run

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Try running your commands again, AFAIK this should work.

Comment: My username was already in the dialout group, I just double checked to be sure

Answer (score 1):

This can be a permissions issue. Try running:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then connect again.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of the answers above solved my problem.

By stopping the ModemManager I was able to free the serial port and use it

```
sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo systemctl stop ModemManager.service 
sudo minicom -s
```

Alternatively the specific LTE modem can be excluded from the ModemManager's management:
https://linux-tips.com/t/prevent-modem-manager-to-capture-usb-serial-devices/284
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/doc/latest/ModemManager/ref-overview-modem-filter.html

To access the serial port without sudo I had to

```
#either add my user to dialout group
sudo adduser $USER dialout

#or make the serial port readable and writable to everybody
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```